# Citrix receiver - Auto login

Tags: pi-2, remote

I am setting up citrix on the Raspberry PI. I have followed [this](http://www.martinrowan.co.uk/2015/10/citrix-receiver-linux-raspberry-pi-2-using-raspbian-jessie/) guide to setup citrix. I have Raspbian also setup to auto login to a certain user. Although I would like now to also auto login to the citrix receiver, but I cannot figure out how this can be done after quite a few hours googling.

Does anyone have any idea/suggestion/comments as to how this can be done?

Answer (score -1):

In all UNIX/Linux systems (that I know) only one user can be logged in at a time on each "terminal" (the console being a terminal, if you connect in via the net, that's a different terminal).  So, what you are asking to do doesn't make sense in a UNIX/Linux context.  However, once you are logged on there are many system facilities for "acting as" the other user.  Look at the commands `sudo` and `su`, for one approach.  It may also be that your goal can be achieved by the correct use of UNIX permissions.

Since your question didn't say why you wanted to do this thing, which sounds silly to my ears after 30+ tears of UNIXing, I can't actually tell you how to achieve that goal.  I can only tell you that the approach you are asking about isn't going to lead anywhere useful.

Comment: The question is about automatically logging into the application _Citrix receiver_ after having automatically logged into Raspberry PI. Not about logging into linux

Comment: OK, this is about logging into an app.  I don't know the app in question, but maybe putting something in the appropriate login script for the user that is logging in.